# How to resolve "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" error in Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

This is my `Django` project structure:

```
Testing
|_djangoApp
|_Testing
| |-- __init__.py
| |-- settings.py
| |-- urls.py
| |-- utils.py
| |-- wsgi.py
|
|_manage.py
|_Procfile
|_requirements.txt
|_README.md
```

I am using `codeship.io` to deploy the build and for pushing it to `Heroku`, which is well configured. On `heroku` i have added an application with the name of "Testing".

I tried to push the build on `Heroku` using `codeship` but it is giving me following error:

```
 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:Testing.git
! [remote rejected] feca277a98c193c3b338ee1bd1406e6bc8f6b9e7 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:Testing.git'
```

Content of Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn Testing.wsgi
```

Content of requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.3.1
docutils==0.8.1
psycopg2==2.4.2
Fabric==1.3.2
South==0.7.3
gunicorn==0.13.4
newrelic==1.0.5.156
django-celery==2.4.2
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-storages==1.1.3
boto==2.1.1
pylibmc==1.2.2
django-pylibmc-sasl==0.2.4
django-sorting==0.1
django-guardian==1.0.3
django-pagination==1.0.7
pyst2==0.4
django-annoying==0.7.6
django-tastypie==0.9.11
django-coverage==1.2.1
django-nose==0.1.3
nosexcover==1.0.7
django-debug-toolbar==0.8.5
Sphinx==1.1.2
django-cache-machine==0.6
django-twilio
```

I just cloned my project from my private repo of `Bitbucket` and added `Procfile` to make compatible for`Heroku`. I tried to follow official documentation but it was only focusing from scratch. What i am missing here? Need help!

Comment: Are both `Procfile` and `requirements.txt` committed to git and being pushed?

Comment: @YuvalAdam Yes! they both are in the same directory

Comment: Well... I have no idea what "codeship" is, so you should check your deployment process against the official docs, you might find your answer there.

Comment: @YuvalAdam Error has now resolved! but after deploying build i am getting :`Application Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is solved now but it is very hard to understand deploying instruction for pre-builded `Django` project to `Heroku` and i would like to explain here:

Let's say your directory structure looks like:

```
Testing
|_djangoApp
|_Testing
| |-- __init__.py
| |-- settings.py
| |-- urls.py
| |-- utils.py
| |-- wsgi.py
|
|_manage.py
|_requirements.txt
|_README.md
```

You can run in the command line with : `python manage.py runserver`

But `Heroku` needs `Procfile` not `ProcFile` or `.txt` to run your django project.

Now, add `Procfile` in same directory where you have `requirements.txt` and edit with following syntax (keep remember about the spaces)

```
web: gunicorn Testing.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Basic `requirements.txt` should contain :

```
Django==1.4
simplejson==2.2.1
lxml==2.3.5
pyyaml==3.10
fabric==1.4.3
unittest2==0.5.1
mock==1.0b1
psycopg2==2.4.5
dj-database-url==0.2.1
gunicorn==0.14.6
gevent==0.13.7
greenlet==0.4.0
boto==2.5.2
django-storages==1.1.5
django-ses==0.4.1 #remove this if you don't use Amazon SES
redis==2.7.1
django-celery==3.0.11
South==0.7.6
```

Now push it to your `heroku` account.

One more point, If you want to push  `Bitbucket` repo to `Heroku` then you can use `codeship.io` as an intermediate tool.

Everytime when you push from your local repo a new build will deploy automatically to Heroku environment.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked you in my comment.

Comment: I am getting the error even after following your instructions. The process I am following is 1) clone my project from github. 2)go to the directory with manage.py and create `Procfile` with `web: gunicorn fbnetworkgraph.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT`.3)create `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.4)change directory to one level up and run `heroku create`. 5) run `git push heroku master`.